Transcription and speaker diarization using pyannotate and whisper
I want to transcribe a recording according to speakers (speaker diarization). I understood I can combine pyannotate and whisper for this purpose. The problem is that pyannotate requires registration using company/ university name and website. I am a student. I don't know which website should I enter. Do you have ideas what should I do? Additionally if there are any references or ideas for implementation of speaker diarization and transcription, I will really appreciate it.
I don't really know how to deal with this problem... i hope to get an answer that will help me find a way to use pyannotate or implement speaker diarization in an alternative way
